Parallel requests gets slow when the list grows
I have created an application using FastAPI that basically exposes a POST route and execute few external requests for each incoming request.
The code is really simple:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from src.utils.logger import create_logger
import aiohttp
import asyncio


logger = create_logger(__name__)

server = FastAPI()

@server.post('/enrich_data')
async def process_gateway_data(payload: Payload, request: Request):
    url = 'https://myid.execute-api.es-east-1.amazonaws.com/mkt'
    mktlist = [{...}] # this list of objects
    data = await load_data(url, features, request_id)
     
    JSONResponse(content={'mkt': {'data': '000', data} })

def _create_mkt_payload(mkt: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    return {
        "mkt_group": mkt['mkt_group'],
        "payload": {
            mkt['name']: mkt['value']
        }
    }

async def make_request(client: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str, mktdata: Dict[str, any]):    
    payload = _create_mkt_payload(mktdata)    
    _id = uuid.uuid4()
    logger.debug(f"{_id} request {mktdata['mkt_group']}")

    async with client.post(url=url, json=payload) as resp:
        mkt_response = await resp.json()

        logger.debug(f"end uuid {_id} status {resp.status}")
        return {mkt['name']: mkt_response}


async def load_data(url: str, mktlist: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=15)) as session:
        for mktdata in mktlist:            
            tasks.append(make_request(session, url, mktdata))
        data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return list(data)

All external requests are made for the same endpoint with a different payload and it responses pretty fast. I have extracted the percentiles from API gateway:
P50 P55 P60 P65 P70 P75 P80 P85 P90 P95 P99
17  17  18  18  19  19  20  21  22  24  30

Based on these on numbers, I have figured out that my application had some bottleneck  because my code only execute like 10 http requests, waiting for response, enrich the payload then return the response but the percentiles from my application are:
P50 P55 P60 P65 P70 P75 P80 P85 P90 P95 P99
66  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  75  80  113

I have added that logger.debug between await resp.json() just to be sure that problem was there.
After a few more tests, I have figured out that more items I had in mktlist more slower my response was - if I have only 1 or 2 items in mktlist, the response from wait json is very close from percentile of external request.
It's very strange because it looks like that something is locking my event loop and right now I have no more ideas how to optimize it.
I really can't have a difference like 20ms-30ms between external app and my application. Both applications are under same AWS account running into ECS.
By the way, I am running using uvicorn with single worker:

uvicorn src.app:server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

What is the explanation why the response time from my application gets so slow if mktlist has like 10 items that will execute 10 external requests? Right now I am testing with 5 rps and 30 tasks (each task is an instance of my application).
Is there any other way to execute parallel requests or anything that I should change to make it faster?

If the responses are so big that the json decoding is taking too long, then you should use resp.read() and do the json decoding yourself (e.g. using asyncio.to_thread() to stop it blocking the event loop).

The responses are small, less than 1kb. How can I use asyncio.to_thread()?

The code is so slow even when I remove the resp.json() and return a fixed json

I misread, mktlist creates new tasks, so the more tasks you have the slower it is. I'm not sure why that's particularly surprising, especially if all those requests are going to the same server, then the server may take longer to process them all. You've also put a limit of 15 connections, so if you have 30 tasks, then it'll take atleast twice as long as 15, even if the server has infinite resources.

@SamBull the destiny is not the problem. The problem is aiohttp that makes slow requests...the response is very different from a curl as example

You need to provide a more complete reproducer to debug further. But, first, you are using 3.10.5? If so, to compare it fairly with curl you need to create a new ClientSession for every request. If the problem goes away, then we know it's related to the connection pool. Then returning to a shared ClientSession, use TCPConnector(force_close=True), if the problem goes away again we know it's a problem with keep-alive connections. If neither of these make the problem go away, then try eliminating the decoding entirely and just use resp.read() and return the bytes directly.
